# MySQL v.5.7.x: What will happen if I remove NO_ZERO_IN_DATE & NO_ZERO_DATE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to **copy** a database to another via **phpMyAdmin** and the process is not completed.

`Error: # 1067 - Invalid default value for 'date_start'`

Have a look in the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `prefix_coupon` (
`coupon_id` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar (128) NOT NULL,
`code` varchar (10) NOT NULL,
`type` char (1) NOT NULL,
`discount 'decimal (15,4) NOT NULL,
`logged` tinyint (1) NOT NULL,
`shipping` tinyint (1) NOT NULL,
`total` decimal (15,4) NOT NULL,
`date_start` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`date_end` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`uses_total` int (11) NOT NULL,
`uses_customer` varchar (11) NOT NULL,
`status` tinyint (1) NOT NULL,
`date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`coupon_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```

See the columns `date_start` &`date_end` that have a default value of **'0000-00-00'**.

If I run the command:

`show variables like 'sql_mode';`

**Result**: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`, `NO_ZERO_DATE` are the ones that "create" the problem.

The question is what will happen if I remove these two?
Should I do it?

Comment: Then your default values will be allowed, but the better solution would probably be, to allow NULL values and set NULL as default.

Comment: @tombom, I have tried to `ALTER TABLE prefix_coupon CHANGE date_start date_start DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;` and I get **Query error**: `#1067 - Invalid default value for 'date_end'`. Note that `prefix_coupon` TABLE has no data.

Comment: You have to change both columns at once. Note, that in the error message date_end is mentioned, although you alter date_start. That's most likely because the ALTER is done with the help of a temporary table. `ALTER TABLE prefix_coupon CHANGE date_start date_start DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE date_end date_start DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;`

Comment: @tombom, you were right. I just fix a typo you had and used this instead `ALTER TABLE prefix_coupon CHANGE date_start date_start DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE date_end date_end DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;`. Thanks!

Comment: So the best solution to my problem would be to find the columns of type `date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'` in all tables, change them with the above query and leave `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`, `NO_ZERO_DATE` as they are.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would recommend.