# How to query database tables structures for DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' and ALTER them in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.7

I am using **MySQL v.5.7.x**.
In a database with 161 tables, one of the them has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `prefix_coupon` (
`coupon_id` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar (128) NOT NULL,
`code` varchar (10) NOT NULL,
`type` char (1) NOT NULL,
`discount 'decimal (15,4) NOT NULL,
`logged` tinyint (1) NOT NULL,
`shipping` tinyint (1) NOT NULL,
`total` decimal (15,4) NOT NULL,
`date_start` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`date_end` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`uses_total` int (11) NOT NULL,
`uses_customer` varchar (11) NOT NULL,
`status` tinyint (1) NOT NULL,
`date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`coupon_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```

See the columns `date_start`, `date_end` and their structure `date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'`?

Is there a way to query database tables for

`date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'`

and `ALTER` them

`ALTER TABLE prefix_coupon CHANGE date_start date_start DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE date_end date_end DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;`

Comment: Nearly a dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228532/mysql-v-5-7-x-what-will-happen-if-i-remove-no-zero-in-date-no-zero-date

Comment: @RickJames I thought the best thing to do was to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find that information in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEFAULT 
from information_schema.columns 
where column_default = '''0000-00-00 00:00:00''';
```

Since MySQL lacks the concept of schema, TABLE_SCHEMA is the same as the database

Note, that the default is '0000-00-00 00:00:00', so ' is part of the value. You, therefore, need to quote with an additional ' to get it right.

When you have fixed the default and whatever data there is, I suggest you set 'NO_ZERO_DATE' in sql_mode to prevent this in the future.

'0000-00-00 00:00:00' have some counterintuitive properties, for example:

```
create table tt (x int, y datetime not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
insert into tt (x) values (1);
select * from tt where y is null and y is not null;
+------+---------------------+
| x    | y                   |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
```

You can change the default value like:

```
alter table tt alter column y set default '1900-01-01 00:00:00';
```

So you can use the previous query to generate alter statements like:

```
select 'ALTER ' || TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TABLE_NAME 
    || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' SET DEFAULT ''1900-01-01 00:00:00'';' 
from information_schema.columns 
where column_default = '''0000-00-00 00:00:00''';
```

Note that you need 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT' in sql_mode for || to work

Comment: I have slightly changed the query to `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_default = '0000-00-00';` and I got the results. Is there a way also to ALTER the columns found in the same query? I mean ALTER as asked in the question.

Comment: You can't change it in the same query (AFAIK), but you can generate ddl statements from the query. I'll add an example

Comment: Actually, all started because of `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`, `NO_ZERO_DATE`. Please read here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228532/mysql-v-5-7-x-what-will-happen-if-i-remove-no-zero-in-date-no-zero-date

Comment: Well, the source database is broken and should be fixed

Comment: I am trying in **phpMyAdmin** to generate the alter statements with this `select 'ALTER ' || TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' SET DEFAULT ''1900-01-01 00:00:00'';' from information_schema.columns where column_default = '''0000-00-00 00:00:00''';` and it gives me errors. I guess I am to novice for this. Could you please explain further? Thanks!

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: The error was ME that I didn't notice... _Note that you need 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT' in sql_mode for || to work_. I am gonna try it again first thing in the morning!

Comment: An alternative is to use the CONCAT function: `CONCAT('ALTER ', TABLE_SCHEMA, ...)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is my final query `SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' CHANGE ', COLUMN_NAME, ' ', COLUMN_NAME, ' DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;') AS EXEC_QUERY FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_default = '0000-00-00';`.